# centre an image in a footer widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I am trying to centre image that sits in a footer widget.  I've read several of the solutions provided here but I am not sure if I am setting up the code right

MY CSS

```
#footer img.center {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

MY HTML

```
<img class="display" src="....">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the class 'center' on your html code :

```
<div id="footer">
   <img class="display center" src="....">
</div>
```

Everything else is fine. and margin 'auto' properties is not working without width. so maybe you can add width of image on your css code.

Comment: That worked a treat! Thanks so much.. I was also missing the div tags :) really appreciate all of you taking the time to answer my question

Comment: @user3017090 , any time your need us. We are here to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

In image class name is `display` . So change you class name in css.

```
#footer img.display {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ND4V/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In your css you defined that the class is **center** (and not **display**), so in your HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
   <img class="center" src="....">
</div>
```